# Coldfusion using class instead of inline style breaks code

Tags: css, coldfusion, styles

Writing in ColdFusion, I have a custom-written menu which drops down or rolls up on a click. When I put the CSS inline with a style statement, everything works fine.  When I replace the style statement with a defined class, the dropdown does not work.

The class navct is:

```
  .navct {
    display:none;
    margin-left:5%; 
    overflow:visible;
    white-space:nowrap
  }
```

The first dropdown "people" uses the class navct and does not drop down.  The second "event" uses an inline style and works perfectly. Here is the relevant ColdFusion code.  .

```
<table border = "2" class = "navbar" >
  <tr>  
    <td> 
      <ul class= "navul" style = "padding-right: 10px">      
         <li style = "color: ##800517;  cursor:pointer" onclick = toggnav('ctpeople','#controllist#')"> People </li> 
           <div id = 'ctpeople'  class = "navct" >
              <ul class = 'navul'>        
                <li><a  href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=PersType">Person Types</a><li>
                <li><a href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=Source">Person Sources</a></li> 
             </ul>  
           </div>

      <li style = "color: ##800517;  cursor:pointer" onclick = "toggnav('ctevent','#controllist#')">Events</li>
         <div id = 'ctevent'  style = "display:none;
                               margin-left:5%; 
                               overflow:visible;
                               white-space:nowrap">
            <ul class = 'navul'>
               <li> <a  href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=EventType"> Event Types </a></li>
               <li> <a  href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=Subevent"> Subevents </a> </li>
               <li> <a  href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=Period">Time Periods </a> </li>  
               <li> <a  href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=Activity"> Activities  </a></li>
               <li> <a  href = "xref1.cfm?basetab=ActStatus">Activity Status</a> </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
       etc.....
```

The javascript toggnav() is

```
function toggnav(id, navlist) {
  var navarr = navlist.split(",");

  navarr.forEach(toggtest); 
    function toggtest(item){     
      var auxbutton = document.getElementById(item);
         if (item == id) { 
           if(auxbutton.style.display == 'none'){
              auxbutton.style.display = '';}
         else if(auxbutton.style.display != 'none'){
              auxbutton.style.display = 'none';} 
    }
  if (item != id) {  
    auxbutton.style.display = 'none'; }  
  }//end of toggtest                      
  }//end of toggnav
```

In tracing through the function toggnav, I find that the item with the class = "navct" is indicated as showing, (i.e. the display none in navct is not functioning) so that it is then set to none.  Adding an inline style of display: none does not fix this.

The results for the second item:

[image]

It seems like there must be something I don't understand using style vs using a class.  Can anyone explain why using the class does not work.  Better yet, can you suggest how to make it work, since the style is cluttering up the code.

Comment: This is a javascript or CSS question and has almost nothing to do with ColdFusion.  I created my own menu script, but after dealing with accessibility, keyboard access, hotkeys, supporting different devices (ie, touch), dynamically adding menus to multiple buttons, menu options not wrapping, adding sub-menus, etc.. I abandoned my homebrew solution when I found the jQuery contextMenu plugin http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/

Comment: You are missing a double quote on the first onclick. If fixing that doesn't resolve the issue, explain how you are including the css. Add another declaration in the css to make sure that works on another element.

Comment: @Dan Roberts -- the double quote that is missing in this description of the problem is present in the actual code -- I must have copied something wrong.  I will try using that class on another element.

Comment: @JamesMoberg -- you are right it is a css or javascript question.  I have not been using jquery.  I think I can stay with my homebrew as my situation is not as complex as yours.  It is just frustrating to have a simple thing like a class break down.